Canon MX410 scan from scanner to computer via wifi
According to the manual Canon Pixma MX410 can scan to a PC by installing software on the PC and pressing scan on the scanner. (Here for the MX490 - this page of the manual seems identical
https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Manual/W/MX490%20series/EN/UG/ug_scanning0600.html)
However, the software seems only to be available for Microsoft Windows: The 'scangearmp2' from https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu/ does not seem to be able to find the scanner.
With Xsane I can make it scan from the computer, but it is more convenient if I can simply select the type of scan on the scanner, press 'scan' and have the document saved on the computer. Right now I scan to USB-stick and move that.
scanimage -L finds the scanner:
$ scanimage -L
device `pixma:MX410_192.168.1.204' is a CANON Canon PIXMA MX410 multi-function peripheral
device `airscan:w1:Canon MX410 series _0B203C000000' is a WSD Canon MX410 series _0B203C000000 ip=192.168.1.204

Can I somehow make Ubuntu receive the scan via wifi?

Read man sane saned sane-pixma  Your model# isn't explicitly supported, but most Canon printers use Canon's BJNP protocol.

A lot of people fail to see the distinction between "using the scanner from the computer" which packages like sane solve, and the possibility (like when using Windows) to scan multipage PDFs using only the scanners display and setting the computer as a target to send the final document to. It's the latter that OP needs. Me as well.

Update for above comment: it seems that Sane supports this use-case using the button-controlled option, nice! I'm going to try this.

Another update: that mode is only for the backend, i.e. when you 1. connect a scanner to your PC via USB, and 2. when you then expose this scanner to your private network to be used by other sane clients. When the scanner is connected to the network via wifi on its own, there is no sane backend involved.
